# Revoking the signin session for Azure AD B2c users is not working for Native applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a solution which has mobile(android & Ios) and web UIs(SPA), both talks to common apis.
We are using the AD B2C for authenticating the users. We have a business need where system administrators deletes the users. We are using the graph api to delete the users in the backend services. This is being done in two steps.

```
    1) revoke the sign in session to kill the active sessions. Document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

    2) Deleting the user account from b2c using graph api.
```

Once the lifetime of the accesstoken is expired the deleted user is getting signed out from the web ui(SPA), but not from the mobile application.

for the mobile application we are using MSALandroid 0.2.2 and for SPA we are using MSAL angular 0.1.4.
Also tried with configuring single and two different applications in ad b2c for mobile and web application.

Am I missing anything mobile application. how to revoke the session from mobile apps as well?

Answer (score 4):

In order to invalidate a user token you need to do things :

1. Call 'invalidate refresh Token' custom action on the user. The call to this endpoint updates the "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" property to dateTimeNow(UTC)
2. Update your custom policies to look at this field when the refresh token is used to get a new access/idToken

These changes checks if the "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" is newer than the refreshToken issued tim. If it is then it means that the old refresh token has been invalidated.

To invalidate a refresh token for a user you need to call this endpoint in graph
`https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/3ff8bee2-d1dc-445a-bca1-64101d478f43/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6`

**Clock Skew**
There is a clock skew to account for the potential difference in observed time between the server that created the refresh token (Azure AD B2C service) and the server that stamps the `refreshTokenValidFromDateTime` value on the user object (the Graph service). It is currently set to 300000 milliseconds (or 5 minutes)

To account for Clock Skew you can update the `ClaimsTransformtion =  AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate`
with this value

```xml
<InputParameter Id="TreatAsEqualIfWithinMillseconds" DataType="int" Value="10000" />
```

Refresh Token invalidation can be called adhoc by the app or you can write an API in your password reset journey that calls graph, or call it on demand when required.  The user that goes through password reset journey in that case will see their session being ended and the user will be prompted on all other devices.

**Changes Needed**

For custom policies the following Technical Profile (TP), Claims Transformation  (CT), and Claims Provider (CP) needs to be added in order for the policy to check if the refresh token was invalidated.

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate" TransformationMethod="AssertDateTimeIsGreaterThan">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" TransformationClaimType="leftOperand" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" TransformationClaimType="rightOperand" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="AssertIfEqualTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
          <InputParameter Id="AssertIfRightOperandIsNotPresent" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
           <InputParameter Id="TreatAsEqualIfWithinMillseconds" DataType="int" Value="10000" />
        </InputParameters>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

...

```xml
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
          <DisplayName>JWT Issuer</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="None" />
          <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">{service:te}</Item>
            <Item Key="issuer_refresh_token_user_identity_claim_type">objectId</Item>
            <Item Key="SendTokenResponseBodyWithJsonNumbers">true</Item>
            <Item Key="RefreshTokenUserJourneyId">RedeemRefreshTokenV1</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
            <Key Id="issuer_refresh_token_key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenEncryptionKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims />
          <OutputClaims />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

...

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="TpEngine_RefreshTokenReadAndSetup">
          <DisplayName>Trustframework Policy Engine Refresh Token Setup Technical Profile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="None" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
```

...

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDate">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

...

```xml
    <UserJourney Id="RedeemRefreshTokenV1">
      <AssuranceLevel>LOA1</AssuranceLevel>
      <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RefreshTokenSetupExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TpEngine_RefreshTokenReadAndSetup" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckRefreshTokenDateFromAadExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDate" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
```

This journey will get called when using the Refresh Token, and actually check for the `refreshTokenLastValidFrom` timestamp that was updated in the Graph API call.

Comment: My problem is revoke of signin session is not happening only for native applications

Comment: Do you mean that in the SPA, silent token call fails once access token is expired and you deleted the account, but in Native App, the silent token call succeeds? Are you using Custom Policies? Because in Native App its using the refresh token, and that graph command is not sufficient. Whereas in the SPA, it relies on session cookies (so graph cmd is not relevant).

Comment: In my app admin users are authorized to del other users
in api when admin tries to delete any user we are revoking as follows
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxuserprinciplexx/revokeSignInSessions
 then deleting the user with graph api from B2C tenant
If the deleted user is logged during the same time, once the token got expired he was getting signed out from browser(SPA).
where as if user is logged in mobile device user is still able to access the system with valid token
yes, the silent token call is getting succeeded in native applications
Yes, we are using the custom policies

Comment: Ok this explains it then. The Graph command is not relevant in the SPA app. In the SPA app, the silent token call opens a hidden iframe, and uses Cookies to determine if the user has a valid session. When the user is deleted, this check fails. In the Native app, it uses Refresh Token to get new Access tokens... and in this case we need to revoke the refresh token. The Graph API call you reference is only part of the solution for Custom Policies (it works as-is for User Flows). I have updated my answer on how to do this for custom policies.

Comment: Also im not sure what the behaviour would be by deleting the user, so test by simply disabling the user, as we need to read the `refreshTokenLastValidFrom` timestamp on the user object. You could put a `defaultValue` for <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" />, and also adjust that it doesnt throw an error on failed lookup by adding the metadata item [RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#metadata):false

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT 

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/breaking-change-invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-update-in-microsoft-graph-beta/

Is this something we need to consider while making the change to invalidate the token. I am really confused what is the correct behavior because this breaking change post was made in 2019 and the answer replied by Jas in 2020.

Comment: @RL89 I tried using "signInSessionsValidFromDateTime" in my custom policy and got this error: "Policy "xxx" of tenant "xxx.onmicrosoft.com" makes a reference to ClaimType with id "signInSessionsValidFromDateTime" but neither the policy nor any of its base policies contain such an element." So I guess its not relevant to B2C, but some clarity in the documentation would be great.

Comment: Only thing you need to do is use the new endpoint name. B2C policy references the raw attribute name, not the value returned by Graph API (signInSessionsValidFromDateTime). The raw attribute name isn’t changing. So don’t change your b2c policy.