# Graph API revokeSignInSessions in Azure AD B2C: have to call twice to completely revoke a refresh token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to revoke refresh token using Graph API revokeSignInSessions to handle case of user logs out. The problem I see is that I have to call the revocation API twice to actually revoke the refresh token.

Following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#1-get-an-authorization-code, using postman, I do step by step:

**Step 1: Get the code**

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6 &response_type=code &redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms/ &response_mode=query &scope=offline_access%20https://{tenant-name}/{app-id-uri}/{scope} &state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
```

**Step 2: Get refresh token by using the code from step 1**

```
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6&scope=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6%20offline_access&code=code%20from%20step%201&client_secret=QHS8i~...
```

**Step 3: Get new access token by using the refresh token**

```
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6&client_secret=QHS8i~...&scope=openid%20offline_access&refresh_token=refresh%20token%20from%20step%202
```

I can get new access/id token from the refresh token. After that I revoke the refresh token by using Graph API revokeSignInSessions.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/revokeSignInSessions
```

Call api and wait after 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 15 minutes and even 30 minutes (for each test) and I can still get new acces token from the refresh token. I also try the Revoke sessions button on Azure portal and have the same result.

And the special thing is that when I call the revoke api for the second time, the refresh token is actually revoked (Includes original token refresh and next refresh token received after the first unsuccessful revocation)

Checked refreshTokensValidFromDateTime and signInSessionsValidFromDateTime properties, they are reset to current date and time as expected after calling the revoke action. Users who are logged in to the browser are also forced to log in again.

The only problem I see here is that I have to call the revocation API twice to actually revoke the refresh token. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong somewhere. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To **revoke** refresh tokens, you can make use of below Graph API query:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user_id>/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
```

To get code, I used same **authorization request** as you like below:

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6 &response_type=code &redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms/ &response_mode=query &scope=offline_access%20https://{tenant-name}/{app-id-uri}/{scope} &state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
```

**Response:**

[image]

I generated refresh token successfully by including above code in POST request like this:

```http
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
code:code_from_above_step
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
scope:offline_access https://sritestb2caad.onmicrosoft.com/api/custom.scope
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using above refresh token, I'm able to generate new **id tokens** successfully like below:

```http
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
refresh_token:refresh_token_from_above_step
scope:openid offline_access
```

**Response:**

[image]

I ran below **graph query** to revoke refresh tokens of an user like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userID>/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, it may take up to **5 minutes** to work after revoking
> refresh tokens from Graph API

When I tried to generate new token using same refresh token now, I got error message saying ***"The provided grant has been revoked"*** like below:

```http
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
refresh_token:refresh_token_from_above_step
scope:openid offline_access
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[user: invalidateAllRefreshTokens - Microsoft Graph beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, I tried your steps, used invalidateAllRefreshTokens api, but still had to call twice for revoking the refresh token. Is it related to the custom policy, API Permission or I'm using Implicit Flow?

Comment: Then I think it's related to custom policy based on how you implemented/configured it. In my case, I used user flow and I'm able to revoke refresh tokens on first attempt without calling the query twice.

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi. I have researched and tried many ways to revoke refresh the token used user flow but still not getting the desired result, not sure why. Then I switched to custom policy and it worked. Solution is updating custom policy to look at refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime and refreshTokensValidFromDateTime fields when the refresh token is used to get a new access/idToken. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475227/revoking-the-signin-session-for-azure-ad-b2c-users-is-not-working-for-native-app.