# What is the recommended Clock Skew value in Azure AD B2C authentication, and why is it set to 5 minutes by default?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Currently in Azure AD B2C service, Clock Skew is defaulted to 300000 milliseconds (or 5 minutes). In my opinion it is quite long and needs to be reduced.

I'm working on the Graph API revoke one.
Following this link [Revoking the signin session for Azure AD B2c users is not working for Native applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475227/revoking-the-signin-session-for-azure-ad-b2c-users-is-not-working-for-native-app) to modify my custom policy. That thread refer to Clock Skew, which is set to default 5 minutes.

Please take a look a this code:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate" TransformationMethod="AssertDateTimeIsGreaterThan">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" TransformationClaimType="leftOperand" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" TransformationClaimType="rightOperand" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="AssertIfEqualTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
      <InputParameter Id="AssertIfRightOperandIsNotPresent" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
      <InputParameter Id="TreatAsEqualIfWithinMillseconds" DataType="int" Value="300000" />
    </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Clock Skew = 300000s (5 minutes).
I assume the refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime is marked at time 00:00:00 and refreshTokensValidFromDateTime is marked at time 00:04:59.
In this case the refresh token would theoretically be invalid since refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime is in the past for refreshTokensValidFromDateTime. But since the difference between the two parameters has not exceeded the Clock Skew limit (4min:59s < 5min), the refresh token will still be counted as valid and the user can still use it to get a new access token.

It seems to me that the default 5 minutes is too long.
Is there a reason that Microsoft defaults to Clock Skew to 5 minutes? If I want to reduce it, what is the right number? Does it matter if I straighten the Clock Skew to zero?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here in the document you can update the value:

To account for Clock Skew you can update the ClaimsTransformtion =  AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate with this value

```
<InputParameter Id="TreatAsEqualIfWithinMillseconds" DataType="int" Value="10000" />
```

More information:https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/512